# Is there a max size for receiving SOAP messages in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, soap

Is there a limit to the size of incoming SOAP messages in Delphi? I have code that receives very large XML SOAP messages, but it's currently failing on ones that are over 50MB or so with this error :

EDOMParseError Exception in TServiceWrapper
Not enough storage is available to complete this operation.

Line: 11

With logging I can see that I'm getting past the BeforeExecute event in RIO with no problem, but I don't make it to the AfterExecute event. I'm not running out of pure storage, but is there a limit to what the DOMParser is allowed to use and is it configurable?

EDIT: Some more information I've found. Part of the issue does seem to be Delphi thread related. I've been able to successfully manually grab the XML response stream from the WebNode and bind if I do it in a standalone exe, but when it's run via thread from my main app, I get the same error message regarding storage.

Comment: 32bit or 64bit? It may not be the amount of memory total, but the amount of memory allocated to a thread.

Comment: @Jerry why would threads have limited memory?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Jerry has the stack size in mind :)

Comment: XML isn't going on the stack. typical stack is 1MB.

Comment: It's a 32 bit process/thread.

Comment: Which Version of Delphi, I found several QC Items that may be related to this as well.

Comment: The basis of the application is D2005, but most of the Soap component source was poached from 2010 and XE1 to solve some of the worst problems we found in the soap libs.

Answer (score 0):

There are several similar errors that are raised by the Operating System.

The following was taken from [Steve Friedl](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/not-enough-codes.html) site.

- Not Enough Storage is available to process this command

  - When running out of memory explicitly, such as via LocalAlloc, or on CreateThread if there are too many threads
- Not enough storage is available to complete this operation.

  - Running out of indirect non-disk resources (file HANDLEs, etc)

[TechNet Suggests](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc978736.aspx) the following:

Do one of the following, then retry the operation:

1. Reduce the number of running programs
2. Remove unwanted files from the disk the paging file is on and restart the system
3. Check the paging file disk for an I/O error
4. Install additional memory in your system.

In addition I make sure you have the latest MsXML Parser installed, I remember this error running under Windows XP and upgrading solved the problem.

Comment: Based on my system monitors, I don't think I'm hitting any actual disk constraints. I was running the process in a separate thread, but I've made a standalone program that invokes the call and it has the same behavior. I'll definitely check the version of MsXML though.

Comment: The newest version of MsXML Parser didn't fix the issue sadly.

Comment: Hopefully someone else might be able to help.